# How can I extract a pattern (start and end) in a big string, using R?

Tags: r, regex

I have a big string and I want to match/extract a pattern with start and end search pattern. How can this be done in R?

An example of the string:

`big_string <- "read.csv(\"http://company.com/students.csv\", header = TRUE)","solution":"# Preview students with str()\nstr(students)\n\n# Coerce Grades to character\nstudents$Grades <- read.csv(\"http://company.com/students_grades.csv\", header = TRUE)"`

And I want to extract the url components in this instance. Therefore, the pattern starts with `http` and ends with `.csv` or any extension (if possible).

`http://company.com/students.csv`

`http://company.com/students_grades.csv`

I have no luck with many attempts using `gregexpr` to extract the pattern. Can someone help with coming out a way to do this in R?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Will it always be a URL to extract?  Always the first and last URL? Always in quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stringr package works very well for this type of application:

```
library(stringr)
big_string <- 'read.csv(\"http://company.com/students.csv\", header = TRUE)","solution":"# Preview students with str()\nstr(students)\n\n# Coerce Grades to character\nstudents$Grades <- read.csv(\"http://company.com/students_grades.csv\", header = TRUE)'

results<-unlist(str_extract_all(big_string, "http:.+csv"))
```

The search pattern is a string starting with "http:" with at least 1 character and ending with "csv"

Comment: `http:.+?csv` maybe better

Comment: Hi Dave, just tested your code actually works on the sample. Thanks! The version of the `big_string` is actually a little bit more complicated than the sample and for some reasons `http:.+/csv` works and the other does not.